# How to autofocus atomic block in draft js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, draftjs

Suppose I inserted a new custom block like

```js
const insertBlock = () => {
    const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();

    const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
      "EDITORELEMENT",
      "MUTABLE",
      {
        a: "b"
      }
    );

    const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
    const newEditorState = EditorState.set(editorState, {
      currentContent: contentStateWithEntity
    });

    setEditorState(
      AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(newEditorState, entityKey, "text")
    );
  };
```

```js
const EditorElement: React.FC = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div className="EditorElement">
      <EditorBlock {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

How do I auto-focus this new block right after inserting it?
Tried many solution using `forceSelection`, `focus` but they didn't work

Comment: Have you tried `useRef`?  It's the standard way of doing this in React.  https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useref-guide/#21-use-case-focusing-an-input

Comment: @jmargolisvt and how do I focus it exactly on the EditorElement? I tried doing it on EditorBlock, but it doesn't implement focus function

Comment: You need to attach it to your `input` element, wherever that is (within your `EditorElement` perhaps?).

Comment: there is no input element. It's EditorBlock from draftjs

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
Carefully read [selection state spec](https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-selection-state).
So, basically, we need `anchor` (or start) and `focus` (or end). Since I want only to move my caret into the block, 0 values are okay for me.
Then, I need an `offsetKey` of the same block I want to select. In my case, I did it by taking a `block` prop from my component `EditorElement`.
So, the whole `useEffect hook looks like this`.

```js
const { block, contentState } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    const key = block.getKey();

    const selection = SelectionState.createEmpty(key).merge({
      anchorKey: key,
      anchorOffset: 0,
      focusKey: key,
      focusOffset: 0
    });

    const { setEditorState } = props.blockProps;
    setEditorState((prev: EditorState) =>
      EditorState.forceSelection(prev, selection)
    );
  }, []);
```